# c# get the directory of the current XML file (not application)

Tags: c#, xml

I have an application which is loading an xml file which is executing c# code through CDATA, that i want to reference a .bat file in the XML which is in the same directory as the XML file and execute it - but i cant find the way to reference that directory.

The xml file is being run through an application so when i use things like:

```
string fileName = "update.bat";
string path = Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,  fileName);
```

I get the path of the application not the current xml file - which could be located anywhere.

I have tried:

`Path.GetFullPath`, 
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` etc as well as ../ and ./ - but i cant seem to find the current xml files path.

Comment: Can you save the path when you load the file?  An XML document has no knowledge of where it come from - it could have been loaded from a string in memory of from a remote procedure call.

Comment: nope the only thing i have control over is the xml file - so whatever command or string i use must go in there.

Comment: How are you opening the XML file in the first place? You have to have a path and filename in order to do so, so you already know where it's located. Remove the filename, and you have the directory. What specifically is the issue? What does *being run through an application* mean exactly?

Comment: you load the xml file through the application manually by browsing to the file.

Comment: and you do not have access to the dialog box where the user selects the file? Show us your code that opens the XML file, please.

Comment: All i have control over is the xml file that is loaded by the application - the open box is just a standard browse window.